# Why are my polygons disappearing when I zoom in on QGIS. Version 3.28.9

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geometries

I have recently downloaded the 3.28.9 version of QGIS and I am having repeated issues of shapefiles disappearing and parts of shapefiles not selecting when pressed. The shapefile disappears when zooming in and the virtual area field in the attribute table becomes a random negative value.

To fix this I have ran the shapefile through multipart to single part, and then fix geometries. I then have to overwrite the current shapefile as copying and pasting the new polygon doesn't work either. This seems to work with the feature but once I edit the polygon it reverts back to this state.

It has only started happening since this updated QGIS download which makes me think it is a version issue rather than repeated broken geometries. If anyone else has had this issue, please let me know how I can resolve it as it keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem with point shapefiles since upgrading to QGIS 3.23.3 Lima. Same shapefiles didn't have this problem with previous versions of QGIS. I solved the issue by removing the *.QIX file associated with the shapefile. The QIX file seems to be unnecessary as I can perform everything I need without it.